# Projection formula for general sheaves

Tags: sheaf-theory

The question of proving the projection formula has been asked before on MSE but for spaces & sheaves with more structure. Here, I only want $\mathcal G, \mathcal F$ to be sheaves on $Y , X$ respectively (Hausdorff, connected, semilocally simply connected, among other things...), and $f: X \to Y$ some continuous morphism, and to show that $$ f_* (f^{-1} \mathcal F \otimes \mathcal G) \cong \mathcal F \otimes f_* \mathcal G.$$

I have already shown that $f_*$ distributes over $\otimes$, so all I need now is to show that $f_* f^{-1} \mathcal F \cong \mathcal F$. I know that $f_*$ and $f^{-1}$ are an adjoint pair, but to me, all that means is that $\text{Hom}_X(f^{-1} \mathcal F, \mathcal G) \cong \text{Hom}_Y(\mathcal F, f_* \mathcal G)$.
I know the result that if $\phi :  f_* f^{-1} \mathcal F \to \mathcal F$ is a sheaf morphism whose induced morphisms on the stalks are isomorphisms, then $\phi$ is also an isomorphism, but I am struggling to concretely write down the stalks of $f_* f^{-1} \mathcal F$.
I have also tried using the universal property of the pull-back sheaf $f^{-1} \mathcal F$ but I don't think that goes anywhere.

**Edit:** As Roland points out, this is not correct in general, but I have sketched out a 'proof' and am not sure where it fails, even when working with the counterexample. Let $\otimes_{ps}$ denote the tensor product of presheaves, and first consider $\mathcal F, \mathcal G$ as presheaves.

I get
$$ f_* (f^{-1} \mathcal F \otimes_{ps} \mathcal G)(U) = (f_* f^{-1} \mathcal F \otimes_{ps} f_* \mathcal G )(U),$$ since I am quite sure that $f_*$ distributes over $\otimes_{ps}$ **(so I think by the universal property of sheafification this would also hold over their sheafifications, which are isomorphic to $\mathcal F, \mathcal G$ respectively?)**

Then by definition of $\otimes_{ps}$ this equals
$$ f_*f^{-1} \mathcal{F} (U) \otimes f_* \mathcal{G} (U),$$ so all I need now is to show that $ f_*f^{-1} \mathcal{F} (U) = \mathcal{F} (U)$.
But this is not so hard, if I work with the presheaf associated to the pullback sheaf $f^{-1} \mathcal F$: applied here, I get $$ (\text{ps}f^{-1}\mathcal F )(f^{-1}(U)) = \{(V,s) : V \supset U, s \in \mathcal{F}(V)\}/\sim $$ where $\sim$ is the quotient relation that we get from the definition of stalks.

Now assuming this is the case, any $(V,s)$ is equivalent to $(U, s\vert_U)$, since the restriction of $s$ to $U = U \cap V$ is exactly $s\vert_U$.
Thus there is a morphism of sections, which commutes with the restriction map.

Where could I have gone wrong here?

Comment: $f_*$ does not distributes over $\otimes$ and $f_*f^{-1}\mathcal{F}\neq \mathcal{F}$ in general. Also, it would be better if you say over what  you take the tensor product.

Comment: I seemed to have proven that $f_*$ distributes over $\otimes$ (over presheaves), so shouldn't this also be the case when we pass to the sheafification by the universal property of the latter? Since this argument is incorrect, is there a different approach I should try to prove the projection formula?

Comment: Yes $f_*$ distributes over $\otimes$ for presheaves, but it doesn't remain so after sheafification. Think about the case of $f:X\to\{*\}$. If you need to sheafify, this is exactly because $f_*F\otimes f_*G\not\simeq f_*(F\otimes G)$. Now the projection formula require hypotheses on $f, \mathcal{F}$ and/or $\mathcal{G}$ and does not hold in full generality so without the kind of hypotheses you have in mind, it will be hard to give a full answer. We often see the projection proved with $\mathcal{F}$ locally free of finite rank.

Comment: Do you have a counterexample for why the formula I have above doesn't hold in full generality?

Comment: Sure : take $f:(0,1]\to [0,1]$ the open inclusion. Take $\mathcal{F}=\mathbb{Z}_0$ the skyscraper sheaf at $0$ with stalk $\mathbb{Z}$, so that $f^{-1}\mathcal{F}=f^{-1}\mathbb{Z}_0=0$ and thus $f_*(f^{-1}\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{G})=0$. Take $\mathcal{G}=\underline{\mathbb{Z}}_{(0,1]}$ the constant sheaf on $(0,1]$ so that $f_*\mathcal{G}=\underline{\mathbb{Z}}_{[0,1]}$ is the constant sheaf on $[0,1]$ (prove it). We then have $\mathcal{F}\otimes f_*\mathcal{G}=\mathbb{Z}_0\otimes\underline{\mathbb{Z}}_{[0,1]}=\mathbb{Z}_0$. So the projection formula does not hold.

Comment: @Roland thank you for this. I have edited my question to add a 'flawed proof', but I can't figure out why it's wrong/where it goes wrong with your counterexample. I'm not super familiar with how to work with the sheafifications though, but if you could shed some light on that, that would be very appreciated

Comment: As I said in my first and my second comment, $f_*$ does not distribute over $\otimes$. You said "by the universal property of the sheafification..." but this is very imprecise. The sheafification of $f_*f^{-1}F\otimes_{ps} f_*G$ is indeed $f_*f^{-1}F\otimes f_*G$, but there is no evidence that the sheafification of $f_*(f^{-1}F\otimes_{ps} G)$ will be $f_*(f^{-1}F\otimes G)$. Again, take $f$ to be the projection onto the point. If $F$ is a presheaf with $F(\emptyset)=0$ then $f_*F$ is a sheaf and is its own sheafification. In particular $f_*(f^{-1}F\otimes_{ps} G)$ is already a sheaf...

Comment: You have the same problem with the second part, that is when you are trying to prove that $f_*f^{-1}F=F$. You are assuming that the sheafification commutes with $f_*$ which is simply not true. But, here, this is not the only problem. Even at the level of presheaves $f_*psf^{-1}F\neq F$. Take $f$ a closed immersion and $U$ an open subset of the complement.

Comment: Thank you for all the help, I really do appreciate it. I get the examples, I just don't see why my working is incorrect beyond the fact that I'm assuming more than is true. It's probably some basic topological problem I'm having. I'll have to think more about it.